# showDialog in flutter is not working in release version of iOS

Tags: flutter

I am creating an app for iOS using Flutter.
For that Application, I am using dialogue in one screen.
For that dialogue, It is showing a grey layer on dialogue in the
release version of iOS but it is working as expected in the Simulator or debug version
There is a grey layer on dialogue I have added my code to anyone facing the same issue?
need help.

```
 static dynamic customPage(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) {
        return CustomDialog(
          insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
          ),
          child: Container(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Positioned(
                      right: 0.0,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          if (Navigator.canPop(context))
                            Navigator.pop(context, true);
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.close,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            size: 25,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  right: 1.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      "images/bind_loader.gif",
                      height: 90.0,
                      width: 90.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      CustomDialougeUtil(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 12.0, bottom: 10.0, top: 120),
                  child: Text(
                    "Please wait while we are confirming your payment",
                    style: bindTheme.textTheme.headline3,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
// this is a Widget that is showDialog
class _CustomDialougeUtilState extends State<CustomDialougeUtil> {
  //State full widget that uses normal timer view to display on dialogue
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615866/flutter-app-show-grey-screen-in-release-mode-but-works-fine-in-debug-mode-instan Found a solution here.

Comment: Could you please clarify how did your fix this issue? Thanks a lot

Comment: @valerybodak Run your app in debug mode and check logs there might be some error in logs but app will run smoothly this is the tricky thing fix that error and run it again.

Comment: Yes. My issue with iOS was: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23047. Thank you.