# The final version of the application from the playstore not working properly but working fine on the emulator

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-play-services

I made this application for home salon services, the application works fine on the emulator but when downloaded from the playstore it's not working properly.

Here is the image of the app working on emulator. [image]

And here is a screenshot of that very page from my physical device, where I downloaded the application from playstore.
[image]

I am using firebase for my backend.

Need some help and this is the link to my codebase.
https://github.com/subhangpati/the_glem_factory

Comment: As you're using Firebase, When you upload the app on play store, its SHA1 key gets changed and generated automatically, get the new generated one from the Play console and update it on the Firebase App in the Firebase console.

Comment: I have already added that. I am working on this issue right now, It has something to do with " incorrect use of parent widget." Will post the answer when I get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Maybe you don't have given internet permission to the app in the manifest so its not picking anything from firebase.

Comment: Well I have intergrated google maps for end users to pin their location where they wanted their services. While doing so I checked and it had internet permission along with course location access.

Comment: I have found this answer more than helpful in my particular case , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615866/flutter-app-show-grey-screen-in-release-mode-but-works-fine-in-debug-mode-instan